# Move mongoDB datafiles from one server to another

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to restore MongoDB data files from `/var/lib/monogdb` to another server in the same folder, as my old server is not running, and I only have the files. Instead of replacing the files, I have changed the `dbpath` in `/etc/mongod.conf` to the folder containing the files.

I have changed the owner to `mongodb` using chown.

When I restart MongoDB, it gets restarted but, but when checking the status, it shows `Active: failed`.

And when checking error in: `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`, I get:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.593+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.593+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.594+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6347,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"thcs"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.4","gitVersion":"44ff59461c1353638a71e710f385a566bcd2f547","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2204","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"22.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.599+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.600+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.600+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.600+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.600+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7422M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.689+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1678085758,"ts_usec":689965,"thread":"6347:0x7fb1b7c56cc0","session_dhandle_name":"file:WiredTiger.wt","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:805:/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.695+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1678085758,"ts_usec":695470,"thread":"6347:0x7fb1b7c56cc0","session_dhandle_name":"file:WiredTiger.wt","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:805:/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.700+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1678085758,"ts_usec":700829,"thread":"6347:0x7fb1b7c56cc0","session_dhandle_name":"file:WiredTiger.wt","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:805:/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.702+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.702+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.702+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":708}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.702+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: In general you can copy the datafiles to a different server. Ensure you copied **all** files, not only a subset. According error message `"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."` the mongod binaries are not the same version. Ensure that you run the same mongod version as on old server.

Comment: Looks like you try to run the files from USB stick (`/media/usb/THCS/`) I don't think, that's a smart option, copy the files to local disc.

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that the mongod process was denied permission to open one of the data files.

> {"t":{"$date":"2023-03-06T06:55:58.695+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1678085758,"ts_usec":695470,"thread":"6347:0x7fb1b7c56cc0","session_dhandle_name":"file:WiredTiger.wt","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:805:/media/usb/THCS/var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}

Make sure the directory and all of the files are owned by the user account running the mongod process, and that the user has read/write permission for all of the files.